# alternative to std::vector for storing references instead of copies of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector, reference

I'm a  Java developer and I'm new to C++.
With Java: I can do the following

```
myArrayList.add(obj);
```

in 'myArrayList' I will find a reference (a pointer) to 'obj'
However with C++: I know that

```
std::vector::push_back(obj);
```

Will insert a copy of 'obj' into the vector and not a reference. This would usually not be a problem if it wasn't for the high number of operations and objects created.

*My problem:*
Performance problems due to high number of created and duplicated objects by using std::vector.
*What I need:*
an alternative to std::vector or some other way to make dynamic lists of references (pointers) without duplicating objects.

PS: I know about making an array of pointers like this

```
MyClass** dynamic_array = new MyClass*[max_size];
```

I can't use this as the *max_size* is never known.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to solve this is to just use pointers. Here is an example:

```
struct N { int x; };

void test()
{
    N temp;
    std::vector<N*> x;
    x.push_back(&temp);
}
```

Comment: @HDRgaming Even though this approach works it is not an appropriate case of raw pointers use. The common rule is ["Use references when you can, and pointers when you have to."](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#refs-vs-ptrs).

Answer (score 3):

You can store a reference wrapper instead:

```
#include <functional>    

MyClass item;
::std::vector<::std::reference_wrapper<MyClass>> items;
items.emplace_back(item);
// accessing an item will involve an extra call of get() method
items.back().get();
```

Note that (unlike in Java) objects are not managed by GC, it is programmer's responsibility to ensure that references object survives long enough so stored reference is valid.

Comment: yes, but a reference_wrapper is an object itself -> more objects created -> memory usage.

Comment: @HDRgaming It's not java, wrapping a pointer/reference into a class doesn't introduce any memory overhead.

Comment: @HDRgaming Creating objects in C++ is does not necessary involve some mandatory overhead. And `std::reference_wrapper` is a dedicated lightweight proxy class that introduces no overhead over raw pointers or normal references.